# How to sum a list of float numbers in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am puzzled with my code:

```
let sum l = match l with
  | [] -> 0.0
  | h::t -> h +. (sum t);;
```

It should give me the sum of the numbers in the list. However when I check the code, I found the second code crashes when I use a list of length greater than or equal to 7. Here is the code:

```
# sum [0.;1.;2.;3.;4.;5.;]

- : float = 15.

# sum [0.;1.;2.;3.;4.;5.;6.]

- : float = 21.
# sum [0.;1.;2.;3.;4.;5.;6.;7.]

- : float = 21.
```

I am really confused because a modification of it, which operates on int, turned out to be normal:

```
let rec sumf l = match l with
  | []-> 0.0
  | h::t-> (float_of_int h) +. sumf t;;
```

and I do not know what is the essential difference between the two aside from I cast int into float in the second code.

Comment: the result of sum [0.;1.;2.;3.;4.;5.;6.;7.] is 28 on my computer. In your first code, let sum should be let rec sum and the last ;; should not be there.

Comment: “- : float = 21.” is not a “crash”.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> let sum l=
> match l with
> []->0.0
> |h::t-> h+. (sum t);;
> ```

Since you didn't use the `rec` keyword here, the call to `sum` in the last line is a call to a `sum` function that you defined beforehand. Apparently that `sum` function was buggy.

Answer (score 10):

I don't understand why your code crashes. When I try your `sum` function with `rec` keyword, I don't have any problem, otherwise you can't call recursively the sum function.

```
let rec sum l = 
  match l with 
   [] -> 0. 
  | h :: t -> h +. (sum t);;
```

You can also use the `fold_left` function in module `List`:

```
let sum l = List.fold_left (+.) 0. l;;
```